# should the join method be in the Course class or the Student class?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, class-design, modeling

The rule I was taught: "the method should be in the Object that it is invoked on"

- a student joins a course => the join method should be in the Course class
- a player drives a car =>  car.drive(..)

but another possibility is:  the join method is in student. the course has an addStudent Method.

the reasoning is "I tell the student to join a course" and "I tell the course to add a student".
I can't tell a course to join a student!

I guess a possible underlying question is: "in Object oriented design, should I think of objects:
 as physical entities where there is a "join" button that I press 
OR as agents which I tell them to do things."

Context: this example was featured in an introduction to SE course that I just started.
we were told to apply the rule and we were not told why does the rule exist.

Comment: Classic bad example. Is the student a sub-object of the course (i.e. cannot exist without)? - No. The other way around? - No. So the relation shoud be somewhere else, e.g. in an EnrollmentRegister where you can register(Course, Student).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! this way course and student don't need to know about each other's methods.

Comment: This question has gotten a lot of downvotes, is there something specific that needs to be improved? or should I ask the underlying question in a new post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you have an operation between two objects which doesn't seem to properly fit into either one of those objects, there are two possibilities:

- The two objects shouldn't be two objects, they should be *one* object.
- The two objects shouldn't be two objects, they should be *three* objects.

In this case, I believe, it should be the latter. The object you are missing is some kind of `Enrollment` that associates students with courses. What you then also need, is a `Register` of `Enrollment`s.

So, you would have something like ([Runnable Example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2wwauxa4R86bzKFnJhM6ww) in [Scala](https://scala-lang.org/), but it doesn't matter, it's all about the design):

```scala
final case class Student(id: Int, name: String) {
  override def toString() = s"Student '$name' <ID: $id>"
}

final case class Course(id: Int, subject: String) {
  override def toString() = s"Course '$subject' <ID: $id>"
}

final case class Enrollment(student: Student, course: Course) {
  override def toString() = s"$student is enrolled in $course"
}

object Register {
  private final val _enrollments = scala.collection.mutable.Set.empty[Enrollment]

  def apply(enrollment: Enrollment) = _enrollments.add(enrollment)
  def enrollments = _enrollments.toSet

  override def toString() = enrollments.mkString("\n")
}

val alice = Student(1, "Alice")
val bob   = Student(2, "Bob")
val clara = Student(3, "Clara")

val introToCs = Course(1, "CS101 - Intro to CompSci")
val compLit   = Course(2, "Comparative Literature")

val aliceInCs      = Enrollment(alice, introToCs)
val bobInCompLit   = Enrollment(bob,   compLit)
val claraInCs      = Enrollment(clarA, introToCs)
val claraInCompLit = Enrollment(clara, compLit)

Register(aliceInCs)
Register(bobInCompLit)
Register(claraInCs)
Register(claraInCompLit)

Register
//=> Student 'Alice' <ID: 1> is enrolled in Course 'CS101 - Intro to CompSci' <ID: 1>
//=> Student 'Bob' <ID: 2> is enrolled in Course 'Comparative Literature' <ID: 2>
//=> Student 'Clara' <ID: 3> is enrolled in Course 'CS101 - Intro to CompSci' <ID: 1>
//=> Student 'Clara' <ID: 3> is enrolled in Course 'Comparative Literature' <ID: 2>
```

Comment: Thanks. Would the same apply to instructor, and lecture for hold? so Session(instructor,lecture),  and session.start(). or would lecture.hold() be better (what we were told in class) or instructor.hold(lecture)

Comment: Hm. That is certainly sometimes a good solution. Listing all enrolled students for a course, or all courses for a student, will be orders of magnitude more expensive though.

Comment: @Deduplicator the register class, can be backed by an in-memory database.so I don't think performance would be an issue.